# ReactJS render tbody data outside table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm render the data into table to create dynamic table.
But tbody data is getting rendered out of table.

**Reproduction link:** **http://codepen.io/sumitridhal/pen/wdoZKR?editors=1010**

**What is expected?**
[image]

**JS**

```
class Table extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
     console.log('constructor');
      super();

      this.state = {
         data: itemStorage.fetch()
      }

     console.log(this.state.data);
   }

   render() {
      return (
                <tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
                  {this.state.data.map((item, i) => <TableRow key = {i} data = {item} />)}
                </tbody>
      );
   }
}

class TableRow extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <tr>
            <td><span>{this.props.data.username}</span></td>
            <td><span>{this.props.data.fullname}</span></td>
            <td><span>{this.props.data.point}</span></td>
            <td><span>{this.props.data.notes}</span></td>
             <td><button className="btn btn-success btn-xs"><i className="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></button>
       <button className="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i className="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
   </td>
         </tr>
      );
   }
}

let tr = $("#table");
React.render(<Table />, tr[0]);
```

**#What is actually happening?**

Data is getting rendered out of table.
[image]

Even `<tr> <td>` tags are missing:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to "design" your application UI fully in react if you have decided to use this library. Therefore declare one root component, bootstrap it and declare the rest of the application layout as children of the root one. Do not use multiple `React.render` calls to insert different components piece by piece.

Here is more or less fixed [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bWaOJp?editors=1010) that is using this suggestion.

Comment: Hi @Amid thanks for suggestion. This suggestion is working for me. I'm new to react. What you suggest to use instead of  multiple `React.render`. Any suggest related to the architecture of application?

Comment: Check my link to fixed pen. There note that your html page contain one entry point: `<div id="app"></div>`. And all UI structure is declared in main `App` component that got rendered into the mentioned entry point. So your app will look like this: Main component <App> that contains some html components + your custom <Table> component. <Table> in turn contain <TableRow> and so on.